# Class Unavailable UIVisualEffectView prior to iOS8

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios8, blur, uivisualeffectview

I realize that I can add UIVisualEffects programmatically, conditionally executed if the class exists, eg.

```
if([UIVisualEffectView class]){

        UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
        UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
        [blurEffectView setFrame:self.backgroundBlurView.bounds];

        [self.backgroundBlurView addSubview:blurEffectView];

        UIVibrancyEffect *vibrancyEffect = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:blurEffect];
        UIVisualEffectView *vibrancyEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:vibrancyEffect];
        [vibrancyEffectView setFrame:self.backgroundVibrancyView.bounds];

        [[vibrancyEffectView contentView] addSubview:self.backgroundVibrancyView];

        [[blurEffectView contentView] addSubview:vibrancyEffectView];
        vibrancyEffectView.center = blurEffectView.center;
    }
```

But is there a way to add the visual effects views in the storyboard, then conditionally remove them in order to be compatible with iOS7? I tried this but keep getting this error:
**Class Unavailable UIVisualEffectView prior to iOS8**

Comment: My advice would be to work with the `UIVisualEffectView` programmatically only, and not add it in IB/Storyboard, since IB/Storyboard files are 'built' during compile time. You need to work with visual effects view dynamically during runtime, to be able to support iOS 7.x.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to see that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. you can change your deployment target to iOS 8+ to kill the error though: 
[image]

Comment: This kills *all* iOS 7 warnings and errors. Wrong move.